# Can an xbox360 be connected to a thunderbolt iMac to be used in target display mode

Tags: imac, display, thunderbolt

I've attempted to do some research, but I've unable to determine if the imac can be used as a monitor (in target display mode) for my xbox 360.

It seems like the only option is some kind of weird converter like the ones that matrox produce for £150! Are there any alternative solutions for input to Thunderbolt ?

Comment: remmeber, you need to have the 27 inch iMac

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can only use a 2010 or 2011 27" iMac with [this Adapter](http://www.amazon.de/Bott-Digital-Video-Link-Apple/dp/B0033SM2CK/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1323284376&sr=8-1).

**iMacs build in 2009 and before doesn't support input signals.**

> iMacs build in 2010 or 2011 support input, but you have to convert the
>   HDMI signal to MiniDisplayPort.

iMacs with Thunderbolt does support input, too. But there is no adapter yet to convert the signals. Thunderbolt is from Intel and they aren't very open about the drivers yet.

EDIT: Found a [german article](http://www.macbug.de/2012/01/08/experten-tipp-den-imac-als-externen-monitor-verwenden-target-display-mode/) about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002HWWDAY)? It's cheap, and seems to do what you need. I'm assuming the Xbox has a HDMI port.

Remember: CMD + F2 is the toggle for Target Display Mode.

Comment: + get a HDMI to Thunderbold converter cable for $7

Answer (score 0):

You will need an HDMI to Thunderbolt adapter, but I don't know if this kind of adapters are produced.

There are some HDMI to DisplayPort adapter, for example the Belkin AV360, but according to this review on amazon doesn't work with the new imac

[DOES NOT WORK on new imacs 2012 with thunderbolt displays](http://amzn.to/13IwfIw)

Comment: Yes and they cost $7.

Comment: It's necessary HDMI to Thunderbolt, not Thunderbolt to HDMI

Comment: XBOX does not have Thunderbolt, but it does have HDMI! Mac has a Thunderbolt. So I use Thundercloud to HDMI adapter, which is the same as HDMI to Thunderbolt :)

Comment: @Buscar웃 are you actually using this adapter to display an Xbox 360 on an iMac in Target Display mode?  Things I find (like https://discussions.apple.com/message/22849461#22849461) say the adapters are not bidirectional.